# Class mx.core::DesignLayer could not be found

Tags: apache-flex, compiler-errors, flash-builder, runtime-error

I am trying to run my Flex project, however on runtime I get the error:
**VerifyError: Error #1014: Class mx.core::DesignLayer could not be found**

So I have added an import statement for the Design layer class: **import mx.core.DesignLayer**, and now I get the error on compile:
**Definition mx.core::DesignLayer could not be found**

What is DesignLayer? Why it could not be found even tough I import it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably building new functionality with an old SDK. Or perhaps you are reusing a third-party component that was built with a newer SDK inside you application built with an older SDK.

In either event the `DesignLayer` class was introduced in Flex version 4, as [stated in the docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/DesignLayer.html). So if you're building your application with some flavor of Flex 3, it makes sense the `DesignLayer` class can't be found, simply because it isn't there.

Go have a look in the framework's source code at `[sdk-path]\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core`. In Flex 4+ you'll find the file `DesignLayer.as` there. Not so in Flex 3.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, my SDK is 4.5.1, indeed I am using third party component - FlashEff, however they support 4.5...

Comment: That's odd. Can you track where the error is coming from? Your code or FlashEff's? In the second case you may want to contact the vendor for support. I see it's included in all their payed products.

Comment: There is no notification for where the error is coming from. I have contacted their support and till now they can't find a solution...

Comment: @Light You may have to do it the hard way then: take out FlashEff and see if the error still occurs. Just to make sure that the error originates there. Now, just a random thought: could it be you are using FlashEff _before_ the Flex framework is initialized (in a preloader for instance)?